# Problem: unable to read repository..." upon installing Eclipse IDE for Java Developpers

Tags: java, eclipse

I really hope you could help me because my studies rely on Java programming with eclipse IDE. Thanks in advance. I had eclipse installed and it used to work properly until one day upon launching it I get "JRE could not be found in path..." error. I then decide to reinstall it to fix it but whenever I launch and proceed with the installer I get "unable to read repository..." error.

Here is the ERROR log:

```
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Executing bootstrap tasks
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] OpenJDK Runtime Environment 1.8.0_252-b09
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Product org.eclipse.products.epp.package.java.2020-03
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup 1.16.0.v20200309-0628, build=4574, branch=1da35020a3c353b5b394468c77f8dc5906f072b7
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.16.0.v20200219-0856, build=4574, branch=1da35020a3c353b5b394468c77f8dc5906f072b7
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.14.0.v20200202-1112, build=4574, branch=1da35020a3c353b5b394468c77f8dc5906f072b7
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Performing P2 Director (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (2020-03))
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Offline = false
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Mirrors = true
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Resolving 23 requirements from 3 repositories to C:\Users\Idriss\eclipse\java-2020-035\eclipse
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Requirement epp.package.java [4.15.0,5.0.0)
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Requirement org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.15.0,5.0.0)
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Requirement org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.15.0,5.0.0)
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Requirement org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Requirement org.eclipse.eclemma.feature.feature.group
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Requirement org.eclipse.egit.feature.group
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Requirement org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Requirement org.eclipse.epp.mpc.feature.group
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Requirement org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Requirement org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla_feature.feature.group
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.context_feature.feature.group
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.git.feature.group
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.hudson.feature.group
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.ide_feature.feature.group
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.java_feature.feature.group
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Requirement org.eclipse.tips.feature.feature.group
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Requirement org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Requirement org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2020-03
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-03/202003181000
[2020-05-17 14:02:17] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
[2020-05-17 14:02:18] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf code=1002 Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest/compositeContent.xml.
java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol family: connect
  at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
  at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:83)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
  at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
  at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient45.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:246)
  at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)

[2020-05-17 14:02:18]
```

Comment: Please add error stack trace to question but as a text.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out I'm new to this comunity

Comment: As always, I would suggest to properly install the Java JDK first manually without any IDE. Proceed after `java -version` **and** `javac -version` in CMD both show the version you want. Then install your IDE. Is there a specific reason your getting Java 8 and not the most recent version, 13? Or at least the most current LTS version, 11?